# Valence API Grade Export

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I've been testing the grade export functionality using Valence and I have noticed while benchmarking that the process is very slow (about 1.5/2 seconds per user).

Here is the api call I am using:

```
/d2l/api/le/(D2LVERSION: version)/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/grades/(D2LID: gradeObjectId)/values/(D2LID: userId)
```

What I am looking to do is export a large number of grades upwards of 10k. Is this possible using this API?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail around how you're measuring this performance? Are you noticing this kind of performance levels with other API calls as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to consider is to get all the grades for a particular user with  [GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/values/(userId)/](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#get--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-grades-values-%28D2LID-userId%29-).
(In your question, it looks like with the call you're using, you're getting the grade values one at a time for each user.)

In future, we plan to support paging of results, in order to better support the case of large class sizes + high number of grade items.  We also plan to offer a call which retrieves a user's grades set across all courses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I hope to see user grades across all course. That would be very helpful.